# IE form action URL issue

Tags: forms, internet-explorer

Recently i am started tuning our products to IE compatability.  Now i am facing a weird problem in IE alone.

My form url is something like this `https://x.com/formurl/dynamicvalue`

and my form element is

`<form action="" method='post'>
...
</form>`

some values the `dynamicvalue` holds are ( **Alphanumeric characters** )

- plan
- plan2
- 1234443
- 544

Except IE every other browsers sending the actions to `https://x.com/formurl/dynamicvalue`

IE form action is sending to `https://x.com/formurl`

I don't know why this is happening, I can replace the document.URL to post the Form back to solve the problem. Still, i want to what's the reason for IE to remove that `dynamicvalue`

I am testing in IE-9

Kindly someone teach me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamicvalue`? A couple examples that cause IE to fail would be helpful here. Also, are you setting the `action` attribute via JavaScript, or are you leaving it blank with the expectation the browser will submit to the same page?

Comment: @JonathanSampson the dynamic value would be a `String` which will be handled in server side(for `PK`) once the page has been submitted. No JS handled for setting up the action. yes i am allowing it empty to post back to the same page.

Comment: Please share a couple examples of the dynamic URLs. Also, if JavaScript isn't involved here, why add [tag:javascript] to the question, or mention `document.url`?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanSampson i did the edits as you mentioned.

Comment: Remove the `action` attribute completely. If that doesn't work change it to `action="#"`.

Comment: @mercator now the form is posted to `https://x.com/formurl/dynamicvalue%23`

Comment: In that case there's something you're not telling us, because that's impossible. Add some minimal, but complete working example HTML-only code to your question. What does the _actual_ HTML source look like? Is the `#` in the actual HTML the browser sees, or is it in a template that your server-side scripting language mangles before it reaches the client?

Answer (score 0):

I have also discovered this bug in Internet Explorer 11 when reading the `action` attribute of a form with `action` set to the empty string.

```
<form action="" method="post"></form>
```

If one reads the form.action attribute in javascript and the current URL does not contain a trailing slash, the last part of the URL will be removed. I.e., if the location is `example.com/xxx/yyy`, `form.action=="example.com/xxx`, while if  location is `example.com/xxx/yyy/`, `form.action=="example.com/xxx/yyy/`.

However, if the form is posted by clicking a submit button, it is posted to the correct URL, i.e., `example.com/xxx/yyy` or `example.com/xxx/yyy/`.

I overcame this by using jQuery's `attr` function to check if `action=""` in the HTML and then I use `location.href` instead.

```
if($(form).attr('action') === '') return location.href else return $(form).attr('action')
```

(Why would someone do this? I am intercepting the form submit and using ajax to send the data. To do this, I need to know where the form wants to submit)

Comment: I solved this by removing the ```action="" ``` part alltogheter, reading .attr might've caused problems in case I was to change the action programatically